# How to use Selenide to check the element is 2 digits?

Tags: javascript, java, junit, selenide

I have no idea how to check if the element has 2 digits or not, in this case, the answer is 19.979999999 as a negative test.

```html
final String HOST = "https://mainortest1.azurewebsites.net/shopping";

@Test
public void totalDecimalIs2() {
    $("#quantity1.product_count_1").setValue("2");
    $("#add1.add").click();
    $("#total_amount").shouldBe(visible);
    //↓Here I am not sure how to check is this total_amount is 2 digits or not, like XXX.YY
    $("#total_amount").shouldHave(???);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you meant 2 digits after the decimal point.

Try the following

**Onetime solution :**

```
assertTrue($("#total_amount").getText().matches("\\d*\\.\\d{2}"));
```

**Reusable solution:**

```
 public static Condition elementHasExactlyNumberOfDecimalDigits(final int digits) {
    return new Condition("elementHasExactlyNumberOfDecimalDigits") {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Driver driver, WebElement webElement) {
            String text = webElement.getText();
            if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }
            return text.matches("\\d*\\.\\d{" + digits + "}");
        }
    };
}

//then anywhere
assertTrue($("#total_amount").has(elementHasExactlyNumberOfDecimalDigits(2)));
```